# C++: Forward iterator interface of a member container to class interface

Tags: c++, iterator, constants, decltype

I'm dealing with a class that has a `std::array<double, 2>` data member and I am trying to implement a few basic iterator mechanics for my class by simply passing everything onto `std::array` (`begin()` and `end()` shall suffice for now).

I am using `decltype` and `std::declval` to infer the return type of `std::array`'s `begin()`.

```cpp
class myCont {
    public:
    myCont() : data({{-1, 1}}) {}

    /* Pass to iterator mechanism of std::array */
    auto begin() -> decltype(declval<array<double, 2>>().begin()){return data.begin();}
    auto cbegin() -> decltype(declval<array<double, 2>>().cbegin()){return data.cbegin();}
    auto end() -> decltype(declval<array<double, 2>>().end()){return data.end();}
    auto cend() -> decltype(declval<array<double, 2>>().cend()){return data.cend();}

    private:
    array<double, 2> data;
};
```

Using `myCont` as a const ref argument yields errors concerning const correctness: *passing 'const myCont' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers*,

```cpp
void myContainerFunc(const myCont& c){
    for(auto it = c.cbegin(); it != c.cend(); it++) // Error
        cout << *it << ' ' << endl;
}
```

while the exact same function taking a `std::array` works just fine.

```cpp
void myContainerFunc(const myCont& c){
    for(auto it = c.cbegin(); it != c.cend(); it++) // works perfectly fine
        cout << *it << ' ' << endl;
}
```

Why don't `myCont::begin()` etc. behave like `std::array`'s implementations, which they are supposed to call? Could anybody point out my error to me? Does `decltype` throw away constness or something similar?

Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to add `const` to `cbegin` and `cend` declarations.

Comment: Indeed, thank you.

Comment: Also, containers will normally have both an `iterator begin();` and a `const_iterator begin() const;` so that plain `begin` does the "right thing" when the container is const-accessed. Same for `end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods `cbegin()` and `cend()` should be const-qualified:

```
auto cbegin() const -> decltype(declval<array<double, 2>>().cbegin()) {return data.cbegin();}
```

If you check `std::array` you will notice that the corresponding methods are const-qualified.